# distcp copy hive table transactional

Tags: hive, transactions, copy, distcp

I have a database in hive that I want to copy to a new database with crypto.
Tables are transactionals.
I used distcp to copy from the first db to the new encrypt one

```
hadoop distcp -skipcrccheck -update /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/old_dbs.db /warehouse/tablespace/managed/hive/new_db.db
```

After, I created a script based on hive commands

```
show create table xxx;
show partitions xxx;
```

Then I adapted this output to change the "location" of the tables.
New tables still empty despite there is a fullfill directory  delta_000001_000001_00000

Any tips?